# How to add call back to Chrome Open External Application popup?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a piece of code that will open a desktop application through Chrome.

```
const openDesktopApp = () => {
    const url = "path/to/desktopApp";
    window.open(url,'_self','');
}
```

Every time this method is called, Chrome will show a [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW7f9.png) if they want to proceed to open the desktop app. This popup is generated by Chrome, how do I add a button handler to the 2 buttons on there? I need to navigate to a different page when they click open and do nothing when they click cancel.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your open tag button

```
href="link to your site that you want"
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, I edited the question, please take a look.